# Zapier CLI, Is there a way to change display order of output

Tags: command-line-interface, zapier

I have a trigger has 200+ output fields, I find Zapier just display them in random order, is there a way to set the order?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When mapping data to a subsequent step, output fields are ordered by popularity. When developing your integration (or before it's had much usage), there won't be much of a pattern here. But, once folks start using it, the best fields will bubble to the top.

In any case, there's no way to manually control the order of fields in the mapping UI.

Answer (score 0):

[Issue #125](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-cli/issues/125) on Zapier's [open-source repo](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-cli) gives context on this issue.  The short answer is that [FieldSchema.choices](https://zapier.github.io/zapier-platform-schema/build/schema.html#fieldschema) does not guarantee order of the properties it returns.  However, that same thread indicates a workaround some particularly zealous members of the community have deployed to force fields into a particular order.

Comment: You're on the right track, but I believe this screenshot is showing the UI when mapping data from a previous step, not items from a static dropdown.